# Shortcodes broken in WP 5?

Tags: wordpress, shortcode, wordpress-gutenberg, wordpress-shortcode

I'm working with a client that needs several sites under their main brand umbrella. We're using wpengine to stage them all, and they all use the same basic css, templates, etc.

The problem is, I developed the first couple of sites with WP 4.9.x installs, which have all been upgraded to 4.9.9. No sweat, everything works fine. I've started staging others though on WP v5 and all of a sudden things are breaking. I've deactivated plugins, etc. to try and find a culprit with no luck.

My biggest headache is shortcodes. I had quite a few custom shortcodes written in functions.php using the WP codex method, and even using the EXACT SAME functions.php file, along with disabling Gutenberg for Classic Editor, my shortcodes are still being displayed within < p > blocks as plain text. I've even attempted to pass the shortcode through the template files using "echo do_shortcode('[custom-shortcode]');" with the output still being plain text.

```
    //from functions.php
    function ihButtonPurp($atts, $content = null) {
    $burl = (shortcode_atts(array(
        "to" => "#"
    ), $atts));
    return '<div class="ih-button"><a href="'.$burl["to"].'"><p>'.$content.'</p></a></div>'; }

    add_shortcode("buttonP", "ihButtonPurp");

    // from template.php
    <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php echo do_shortcode('[buttonP to="#"]Some Link[/buttonP]'); ?>

    //both uses result in plain text output
```

This exact same php and shortcode still works on my WP 4.9.9 sites. Why is this not working with WP 5?

Comment: Did you try installing classic editor plugin?

Comment: Yes, Classic Editor is installed and Gutenberg is disabled via Settings->Writing, per the plugin instructions

Comment: Do you achieve this? Im having the same problem, shortcodes are not working for me